# For how many positive integers $n<2^{10}$ is it true that $G(n)=2$?

Tags: combinatorics

For any positive integer $n$, let $G(n)$ be the number of pairs of adjacent bits in the binary representation of $n$ which are different. For example, $G(10)=3$ because the bits of $1010_2$ change at all three places and $G(12)=1$ because the bits of $1100_2$ change only from the fours to the twos place.

For how many positive integers $n<2^{10}$ is it true that $G(n)=2$?

I know I'm searching for a 1-1 Correspondence but I just can't discover any!  Thanks in advance for posting a solution!

Comment: I'm assuming all numbers start with 1, ie no leading zeros? So it must be of form 1-0-1~ where 1- can be n=1 to 8 ones, 0-  can be m= 1 to 9-n zeros and 1~ is k=1 to 10-n-m ones.  That should be $\sum_{n=1}^8\sum_{m=1}^{9-n}\sum_{k=1}^{10-n-m}1$, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: In order to get exactly $2$ changes, the binary representation must have the form $1^r0^s1^t$, where the exponents are positive integers indicating the number of repetitions of the binary digit in question. (That is, $1^10^21^3$ represents the binary number $100111$.) If $n<2^{10}$, then $n$ has at most $10$ bits. We can simplify matters a little by extending $n$ to an $11$-bit number beginning with $0$, then $G(n)=2$ if and only if the $11$-bit string representing $n$ in binary has $3$ changes of digit, i.e., if and only if it has the form $0^q1^r0^s1^t$ for positive integers $q,r,s$, and $t$ whose sum is $11$. Now you have a standard [stars and bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Is the answer $165$?

Comment: @YunaKun: I’m afraid not. Can you show me what you did to get that?

Comment: $\binom{11}{3}=165$

Comment: @YunaKun: Ah, okay; the lower number is fine, but the upper number should be $11+4-1=14$. In terms of the stars and bars model you have $11$ stars and $4-1=3$ bars to distribute, for a total of $14$ symbols, $3$ of which must be bars. Thus, you should get $\binom{14}3=364$.

Comment: $364$ is incorrect, I don't understand.

Comment: @Regina: You’re right. I must have been asleep when I wrote that: it’s the number of solutions to $q+r+s+t=11$ in *non-negative* integers, and here they need to be positive. It should of course be $\binom{11-1}{4-1}=\binom{10}3=120$. Thank you very much for catching that.

Comment: @YunaKun: My apologies: your $165$ is wrong, but my $364$ is worse. I inadvertently gave you the number of solutiosn to $q+r+s+t=11$ in *non-negative* integers, and here they have to be *positive* integers. The correct answer is therefore $\binom{11-1}{4-1}=\binom{10}3=120$. In the stars and bars model we are placing $3$ bars in different spaces between adjacent stars in a row of $11$ stars; there are $10$ such spaces, and we need to choose $3$ of them.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for all their help!

Comment: @YunaKun: You're welcome. I'm sorry about the earlier confusion.